Where does sensory pleasure lie in the common theories of human desire?
Most basic theories I've read so far like Maslow’s, Reiss' etc. outline similar needs in a different form (Reiss' seemed being more detailed and focused on the social aspect) but where does the pursuit of sensory pleasure lie in those? Things like pretty visual (fireworks, for example), auditory (music) and such? Cases where people specifically seek those stimuli and receive dopamine when achieved?
